# Puppet Environments

Tags: puppet, aws-opsworks, puppet-enterprise

How to Change default production environment to Development in puppet enterprise version 5.5.2.

I tried soem steps but i got "Local environment: 'DEV' doesn't match server specified node environment 'production', switching agent to 'production'" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the command that I run, on the agent, to change my environment:
`puppet config set --section agent environment development`
On Linux, you can see this change in:
`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`
you should see something like this:
`...`
`[agent]`
`environment = development`

Comment: Specifying
[agent]
environment = development


In master console (after creating group)
go to Rules Tab.In fact select agent specified environment and give the name of the environment as 
development.Nodes which matches the environment will dynamically added to the group.

Answer (score 1):

```
Specifying in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet.conf
[agent]
environment = dev
report = true
pluginsync = true
runinterval=31557600

In master console (after creating group)
go to Rules Tab.In fact select agent specified environment and give the name of the environment as dev.Nodes which matches the environment will dynamically added to the group.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain where in PE's control panel you can set this, though I would expect it to be in there somewhere.  If you're willing and able to modify Puppet's configuration files, however, then it's the [`environment`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration.html#environment) property that you want to twiddle, and for this purpose, you should set it in the `[master]` section.  It has different meaning in other sections, so do not set it globally.  And of course, it's therefore *on* the master were you need to set it.